# progressBar loader set in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, progress-bar, loader

How to progressBar loader set in Recyclerview starting and ending??
My progressbar:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress" >
</ProgressBar>
```

Java code:

```
recyclerView = (RecyclerView) drawer.findViewById(R.id.pending);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) drawer.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

This is my code. First i hide the recyclerview and visible the loader but that is not working.

Comment: you want to show a progressbar in each row and update its visibility based on some condition?

Comment: I want only data display beforeonly.

Comment: Please anyone help me

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to do

Comment: I updated my code check now.